# Pytorch C++ (Libtroch), using inter-op parallelism

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, pytorch, libtorch

I am working on a machine learning system using the C++ API of PyTorch (`libtorch`).

One thing that I have been recently working on is researching performance, CPU utilization and GPU usage of `libtorch`. Trough my research I understand that Torch utilizes two ways of parallelization on CPUs:

- `inter-op` parallelization
- `intra-op` parallelization

**My main questions are**:

- difference between these two
- how can I utilize `inter-op` parallelism

I know that I can specify the number of threads used for `intra-op` parallelism (which from my understanding is performed using the `openmp` backend) using the `torch::set_num_threads()` function, as I monitor the performance of my models, I can see clearly that it utilizes the number of threads I specify using this function, and I can see clear performance difference by changing the number of `intra-op` threads.

There is also another function `torch::set_num_interop_threads()`, but it seems that no matter how many interop threads I specify, I never see any difference in performance.

Now I have read [this PyTorch documentation article](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cpu_threading_torchscript_inference.html) but it is still is unclear to me how to utilize the inter op thread pool.

The docs say:

> PyTorch uses a single thread pool for the inter-op parallelism, this thread pool is shared by all inference tasks that are forked within the application process.

**I have two questions to this part:**

- do I need to create new threads myself to utilize the `interop` threads, or does torch do it somehow for me internally?
- If I need to create new threads myself, how do I do it in C++, so that I create a new thread form the `interop` thread pool?

In `python` example they use a `fork` function from `torch.jit` module, but I cant find anything similar in the C++ API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Questions

> difference between these two

[image: intra_inter]

As one can see on this picture:

- `intra-op` - parallelization done **for single operation** (like `matmul` or any other "per-tensor")
- `inter-op` - you have multiple operations and their calculations can be intertwined

`inter-op` "example":

- `op1` starts and returns "Future" object (which is an object we can query for result **once this operation finishes**)
- `op2` starts **immediately after** (as `op1` is non-blocking right now)
- `op2` finishes
- we can query `op1` for result (hopefully finished already or at least closer to finishing)
- we add `op1` and `op2` results together (or whatever we'd like to do with them)

Due to above:

- `intra-op` works without any additions (as it's PyTorch handled) and should improve the performance
- `inter-op` is user driven (model's architecture, `forward` especially), hence **architecture must be created with `inter-op` in mind!**

> how can I utilize inter-op parallelism

Unless you architectured your models with `inter-op` in mind (using for example `Futures`, see first code snippet in the link you posted) you won't see any performance improvements.

**Most probably**:

- Your models are written in Python, converted to `torchscript` and only inference is done in C++
- You should write (or refactor existing) `inter-op` code in Python, e.g. using [`torch.jit.fork`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.jit.fork.html#torch.jit.fork) and [`torch.jit.wait`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.jit.wait.html#torch.jit.wait)

> do I need to create new threads myself to utilize the interop threads, or does torch do it somehow for me internally?

Not sure if it's possible in C++ currently, can't find any `torch::jit::fork` or related functionality.

> If I need to create new threads myself, how do I do it in C++, so that
> I create a new thread form the interop thread pool?

Unlikely as C++'s API's goal is to mimick Python's API as close to reality as possible. **You might have to dig a little deeper for source code related to it and/or post a feature request on their GitHub repo if needed**

Comment: Thank you for insightful answer, and editing my question, I will try to work on that! I too cant find any corresponding fork functionality in C++ API, which is a shame as I would like to run f.exp. two different parts of a model concurrently. I may look into it more, and possibly post a feature request on github. As a last question, would you say it is worth to convert models into torchscript if I have them as torch::Module in my code? right now we serialize the torch::module model into torch::output_archive, and save the bytes ourself, and load them trough input_archive.

Comment: @Bohaterowicz torchscript might improve performance due to graph optimisations (layer fusion and so on). Worth checking out, also there are incremental improvements over it for each new PyTorch release.